# Does PDOStatement::rowCount() issue a SQL query?

Tags: php, pdo

[PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) can be used to get the number of rows affected by the last `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`.

Does it have the overhead of issuing a second request, such as MySQL's [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count), or is the number of affected rows part of the metadata it receives when executing the statement itself, and as such is "free" resource-wise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've enabled the mysql log with:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

And then ran an insert query with prepared statement followed by a `rowCount` call. The log shows this:

```
32 Prepare  INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ?)
32 Execute  INSERT INTO test VALUES(NULL, '11', '22')
32 Close stmt
```

So there is no extra call.

Comment: Great methodology - the number of times I've spent ages debugging PDO, and I've not once turned on the query log. Genius.

Comment: @adam I had to do it 2 days ago..It's the only way of seeing the full query with parsed parameters..